# Does English (proper) allow "sharp ass claws"

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement

we know what a person means to say when they say "the guinea-pig has some sharp ass claws" but I was wondering if the term ass actually allowed in terms of proper english.

if not, then this statement should be read as "the guinea-pig has some shap ass-claws"?

Comment: "The guinea pig has some sharp-ass claws"

Comment: What do you mean by "proper English"? Sticking the word "ass" into sentences like this (what I call ass-intensification) is a feature of highly informal English and would be considered crude and inappropriate in more formal registers. By "proper" do you mean _formal_? Or are you asking whether this usage is _grammatical_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xkcd comic https://xkcd.com/37/

This would be understood to mean "sharp-ass claws" where "sharp-ass" means something like "extremely sharp".  Adding "-ass" to an adjective to intensify it is a fairly recent innovation in English. There was [discussion on wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:-ass) if -ass should be analysed as a suffix or not

You ask if something is "allowed". That isn't really a sensible question. You are "allowed" to do anything.  Certainly people do use "-ass" to intensify an adjective. However it is very casual in register, not part of formal English. It is also predominantly American.

Answer (score 4):

It's slang, not 'proper English', but the meaning is very different depending on where you put the hyphen.

> Sharp-ass claws

Its claws are remarkably sharp

> Sharp ass-claws

It has claws in its posterior... rather unlikely.